# Perform segue in Container View

Tags: ios, segue

Is there a way in iOS to perform a segue in a container view?

In my app I have the main view which has a custom header and, below it, a Container View.

At the load I linked a embed segue from the container view to the starting subview.
Then I linked a segue from the tap on a button in the header to show another view but the new view gets the whole window, it doesn't go into the container view.
Is there a way to make the segue happens in the container view?

The button that triggers the segue is in the header.

Comment: is your header view or button  in your container view ? not getting your question properly!

Comment: You need to add an UINavigationViewController inside your ContainerView.

Comment: can you add some screenshots to elaborate more your ques ?

Comment: Create a custom segue that installs the new controller's view where you want it.